# Multiple qq plots in one figure

Tags: python, plot, quantile, qq

I have a matrix mEps which is of shape `(10, 1042)`, where `10` is the number of assets, and `1042` is the amount of datapoints. I want to show the Q-Q plot for each asset, so I can plot:

```
for i in range(iN):
    sm.qqplot((mEps[i,:]), fit = True, line='q')
```

However, then I get 10 pictures of Q-Q plots. I would like to have them in one figure, so I have the following code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3, figsize=(15,10))
ax= axes.flatten()
for i in range(iN):
   sm.qqplot((mEps[i,:]), fit = True, line='q')
```

This code creates the figure, but it doesn't fill it with Q-Q plots.. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I don't know this statsmodel function, but looking [at their docs](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html), I assume you have to add `ax = ax[i]` to fill your subplots sequentially. It would be good to have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, I already tried that. But if I add:   ax = ax[I].sm.qqplot(...)  , I get the error: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'qqplot'

Comment: `ax` is a parameter of the function as you can see in their docs: `sm.qqplot((mEps[i,:]), fit = True, line='q', ax = ax[i])`

Comment: Great, thank you! Sorry I'm still really new to Python

Comment: Next time, please provide an Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I had to guess what sm.qqplot refers to. Imports are part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

QQplot documentation https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html
states that function takes as argument "ax" the ax in subplots, where you want to place your qqplot

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10,4))

qqplot(data_a['metrics'], line='s', ax=ax1)
qqplot(data_b['metrics'], line='s', ax=ax2)
ax1.set_title('Data A')
ax2.set_title('Data B')

plt.show()
```